# JSON.NET reader problem

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

i got some problem when i generate .json file from spring .json ,and i got this format

```
{ "models": [
    {
        "id":1,
        "modelName":"dfdsf",
        "created":{
            "userFullname":"demo",
            "time":"150301",
            "date":"20110208",
            "userId":"123"
        },
        "remark":"dsfdf",
        "updated":"~unique-id~1"
    },
    {
        "id":2,
        "modelName":"test",
        "created":{
            "userFullname":"test",
            "time":"150301",
            "date":"20110210",
            "userId":"124"
        },
        "remark":"test",
        "updated":{
            "userFullname":"test",
            "time":"150301",
            "date":"20110209",
            "userId":"test"
        }
    }
]}
```

first time i used JObject Parse for convert

```
JObject job = JObject.Parse(fullJson);
```

and the other hand i used jtoken to focus "models"

```
JToken jDetail = job["models"];
```

but the problem is `{[{  xxx  }]}` it look like jarray i don't have any idea to convert it

i ever use JArray, JsonTextReader but it doesn't work.

could suggestion some? because if i pass this ll i set some value to object.

thank you for every idea.

Comment: I have something similar working via `JavaScriptSerializer` - or ar you tied to json.net?

Comment: yes ,i tried on vs2008 ( c# ) but have some idea,'ll post it ,Thank for suggest :)

Answer (score 2):

```
string fullJson = File.ReadAllText("TextFile1.txt"); // for brevity
var job = JObject.Parse(fullJson);
var models = job.Value<JArray>("models");
Console.WriteLine(models[0]);
```

result:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "modelName": "dfdsf",
  "created": {
    "userFullname": "demo",
    "time": "150301",
    "date": "20110208",
    "userId": "123"
  },
  "remark": "dsfdf",
  "updated": "~unique-id~1"
}
```